# A function that is differentiable on irrationals but discontinuous on rationals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Can I construct a function $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ that is discontinuous on $\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$, but $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{|h|^k}=0$ holds for all $x\in [0,1]\backslash\mathbb Q$ and $k>0$

I try $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\chi_{(0,q_n]}$ where $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the sequence of rationals on $(0,1)$. But it doesn't seem to be differential, even when the converge speed is faster than $\frac1{2^n}$.